# Return Observable of single item from http.get in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, observable

I have a service that sends requests to an in-memory-web-api. The service includes a method which I want to query (via query string) the API for a single item.

Regardless of specifying a single item in the generic http.get method I am returned an array.

This differs from if a I make a call to the API for a single item using an ID rather than a query when I am returned just the single item.

```
this.http.get<ITrack>(`api/tracks/1`)
  .subscribe(track => console.log(JSON.stringify(track)));
```

returns

```
{"id":1,"artist":"Radiohead","name":"OK Computer","durationSeconds":61,"nominator":null,"playlistPosition":1}
```

Where as

```
this.http.get<ITrack>(`api/tracks/?playlistPosition=1`)
  .subscribe(track => console.log(JSON.stringify(track)));
```

returns

```
[{"id":1,"artist":"Radiohead","name":"OK Computer","durationSeconds":61,"nominator":null,"playlistPosition":1}]
```

I can get the second call to return just the item with the following:

```
this.http.get<ITrack>(`api/tracks/?playlistPosition=1`)
.pipe(
  map(t => t[0])
)
.subscribe(track => console.log(JSON.stringify(track)));
```

However I can't use methods like single or first as the compiler is expecting a return type of ITrack.

What is the correct way to return a single item here?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming too much from http.get() and expecting it to either convert to the type specified in http.get(<T>) or throw an error when it is expecting ITrack but receives ITrack[]. You comment pretty much answers my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if the endpoint always returns a list, call the `get` method typed with an `ITrack`-array.

Simply replace `.get<ITrack>(...)` with `.get<ITrack[]>(...)`.

Comment: Thanks - I need to get myself a rubber duck!